# Compare current and next record using Hive SQL Query

Tags: hive

My RFID tag file has huge amount of data and data was grouped by Date & Time value (every group has multiple tags) . I would like to know missing Tag #  between 1st set and 2nd set of the data.
Please help me here…

Sample file:

```
field names: Tag #      Date & Time
1st line -> 00045512|05-01-2013 12:02:03
2nd line -> 00052450|05-01-2013 12:02:03
```

Same file continued with different times but missing 1st line from above 2 set sorted by time..(below)

**00052450|05-01-2013 13:02:03**

Basically I would like to find missing tag when my 'Date & time" field changes.

This is similar problem solved in SQL...(link attached)
http://www.milesdennis.com/2011/06/comparing-current-and-previous-records.html

Comment: showing more input and examples of output would help. When you say "sets of data", are you comparing different files or different tables or ?; how are you managing those sets?

Comment: Set 1 (2 items)
00045512|119|59|55|60|50|C|00|N/A|4050|05-01-2013 12:02:03
00052450|120|60|44|60|43|C|00|N/A|4050|05-01-2013 12:02:03

Set2 (1 item and 45512 is missing)
00052450|120|60|44|60|43|C|00|N/A|4050|05-01-2013 12:12:03                      I would like to find missing item (00045512) in second set. Baiscally in 2nd set I have to compare the data with 1st set Items.

Answer (score 0):

Use left outer join:

```
select s1.tag, case s2.tag when null then 1 else 0 end  as missing_flag 
from 
    set1 s1
    left outer join set2 s2 on (s1.tag=s2.tag)
```